# With awk, how can I delete the current line if the previous has the same $3 value?

Tags: text-processing, awk

as the title says, how can I compare the current $3 with the previous line's $3, and, if equal, delete the current line?

So for example this file

```
100.824 4 Packet to 
101.027 1 Received  
102.23 1 Received  
229.393 4 Packet to
229.605 1 Received
```

Becomes

```
100.824 4 Packet to 
101.027 1 Received  
229.393 4 Packet to
229.605 1 Received
```

Comment: For that input `uniq -f2` should also work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To "delete the current line", simply do not print it.

So what you want to do is to print the current line only if its 3rd field *is different* from the previous line's 3rd field.

This requires us to save the 3rd field in a variable to be able to compare the next line's 3rd field to it.

```bsh
awk 'NR == 1 || $3 != prev; { prev = $3 }' file
```

This prints the first line unconditionally, and also any line whose 3rd field is different from the value in `prev`.  This is equivalent to

```bsh
awk 'NR == 1 || $3 != prev { print $0 } { prev = $3 }' file
```

but we're using the fact that the default action for a when conditional test is evaluated to *true*, is to print the current line.

Once output has happened or not happened, `prev` is set to the current line's 3rd field for use when processing the next line.

Example:

```
$ cat file
1 2 3
1 2 3
a b c
d e f
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

```
$ awk 'NR == 1 || $3 != prev; { prev = $3 }' file
1 2 3
a b c
d e f
1 2 3
```

Given your example file, the `awk` script would produce

```
100.824 4 Packet to
101.027 1 Received
229.393 4 Packet to
229.605 1 Received
```

If you can guarantee that the first line's 3rd field is *always non-empty*, then you may simplify the `awk` command into

```bsh
awk '$3 != prev; { prev = $3 }' file
```